# Round a number up to two decimal places regarding 3rd decimal digit

Tags: java, rounding, rounding-error

I am using this function:

```
public static Double arrondi(Double number) {
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
    df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.UP);
    String localProportionAfterRound = df.format(number).replace(",", ".");
    return Double.parseDouble(localProportionAfterRound);
}
```

I want to round the number if the 3rd decimal number is greater than or equal to 5

There is some examples for the output which I want to have:

```
    arrondi(1941.8849999999998) ==> 1941.89 (1941.885 ==> 1941.89 **Correct**)
    arrondi(647.259) ==> 647.26 **Correct**
    arrondi(145.83333333333334) ==> 145.83 ( **Incorrect** , I got 145.84)
```

Is there a way to achieve this? My function should always receive a double and return a double as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved with this where places is the amount of decimals you prefer.
In your case you would call the function with places being equal to 2

```
public static double round(double value, int places) {
    if (places < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();

    BigDecimal bd = BigDecimal.valueOf(value);
    bd = bd.setScale(places, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    return bd.doubleValue();
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply, I have already tested this before, for round(1941.8849999999998) it returns 1941.88 which is not correct, it should be 1941.89